# Warning: strstr(): Empty needle in /home1/.........l/wp-content/plugins/events-manager/em-posts.php on line 257

Tags: wordpress, strstr

I was working on event manager plugin and I made some changes which resulted to below error !

> Warning: strstr(): Empty needle in /home1/....../public_html/wp-content/plugins/events-manager/em-posts.php on line 257
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/....../wp-content/plugins/events-manager/em-posts.php:257) in /home1/...../public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1178

My website is not working and display above error. Also, I am failed to login to wordpress platform that is showing above error.

Comment: Have you used `header('Location:')` in your changes ?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner I was adding some changes in Event manager plugin in wordpress. I was doing changes in category url and something wrong happend. Will you please help me out how to resolve this. My site can't display anything. same errors showing.

Comment: You need to put the changes here then and then anyone can help you out.
My guess is that you have put `header('location:someURLhere');` and it is causing the issue because you can not use `header` after output begins to start.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner I was doing some changes in Event manager plugin    to change the customize location and event url like ...abcd.com/event/....  & abcd.com/location to some other but by mistakenly i removed Event & location from url and enter. From then this issue coming.

Comment: can you please put your changed code here ?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner thanks ! Issue has been resolved.

Comment: Glad you managed it !